# Find all holomorphic functions such that $g(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{n+3}{5n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all holomorphic functions $f: D_{1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $$f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{n+3}{5n+1}$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$ and $n\geq 2.$ where $D_1:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|\;|z|<1\}.$

My initial idea was to rewrite the function in a way that would allow it to be holomorphic but I have been struggling with the way to do it.
I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Look at the function $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{1+3z}{5+z}$ and its values at the points $1/n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing $n=\frac1x$ gives a possible $f$ as $f(x)=\frac{1+3x}{5+x}$, which is indeed holomorphic on $D_1$. Since the specified points accumulate at the origin, the identity principle implies that $f$ is the only admissible function.

Comment: Nevanlina theory is not needed here, since the zeros are accumulating to $0$ a point of the interior. The identity principle gives that the difference is zero.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. If I have figured out correctly what you are saying, so first we substitute  $\frac{1}{n}$ with $x$, which is holomorphic on $D_1$,  now "Since the specified points accumulate at the origin" is the part where I get confused. I don't get how they accumulate at zero. Could you explain?

Comment: @variableXYZ $(1/n)_{n=2}^\infty$ is a sequence converges to $0 \in D_1$, which could be verifed via basic definitions in Calculus. If $g$ is another holomorphic function satisfying everything, then $f,g$ agree on a subset of $D_1$ with an accumulation point also in it. For holomorphic functions we have the idetity principle, so $g = f$ must hold.